# problem with pip install tensorflow-gpu on window 11

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have problems to install tensorflow-gpu on a windows 11 system, Version pandas =2.0.3, Version numpy =1.23.5, Version tensorflow = 2.12.0, Version matplotlib = 3.7.2, Python-Version = 3.11.2, CUDA 11.2, CuDNN 8.6

Code: pip install tensorflow-gpu

I got a strange error:

PS C:\Users\jdrew> pip install tensorflow-gpu
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
Downloading tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [44 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in **init**
parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_tokenizer.py", line 165, in raise_syntax_error
raise ParserSyntaxError(
setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
python_version>"3.7"
^

```
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2i_rvfu4\tensorflow-gpu_6ac9a3d3e88a425cbd0be51ebcfb9128\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
      setuptools.setup()
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 77, in _install_setup_requires
      dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 901, in parse_config_files
      self._finalize_requires()
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 596, in _finalize_requires
      self._move_install_requirements_markers()
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 636, in _move_install_requirements_markers
      inst_reqs = list(_reqs.parse(spec_inst_reqs))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\jdrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
      raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
  setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
      python_version>"3.7"
                    ^
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Comment: Kindly check the [Hardware and Software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements)  to install TensorFlow with GPU setup. Please install all the required software (Nividia GPU driver, CUDA and cuDNN) and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the same link to enable GPU support in your system.